Lining up dotplot with violin plot
I am trying to create a violin plot figure with the raw data points (and means) overlayed, but the data points and means do not match up with the violin plot. Any advice to fix this would be appreciated.
The data points are relative percent cover of litter at 5 treatments at 2 locations.
ggplot(litter, aes(Site, SppCov, fill = factor(trtlit)))+
  geom_violin()+
  theme(axis.ticks = element_line(colour = "black", size = 2), axis.ticks.length = unit(0.2, 'cm'),axis.text=element_text(size=18))+
  cleanup+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('white','grey','steelblue','chartreuse3','darkorange'))+
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = 'y',stackdir = 'center', dotsize = 0.4)+
  stat_summary(fun.data = "mean_se", geom = "pointrange", color = 'black', size = 0.75)+
  stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.1)+theme(legend.position = "none")



Use position = position_dodge(width = 0.9) in each of the layers that you want to dodge. See ?position_dodge.

The issue is that by default geom_violin uses position="dodge" whereas geom_dotplot or stat_summary default to position="identity". Hence, as already pointed out by @Axeman in the comments, to fix that and align all layers you have to set the same position=, i.e. explicitly set position = position_dodge(width = .9) in the geom_dotplot and stat_summary layers, where width = .9 is the default dodge width used by geom_violin (be aware though that this might differ, e.g. a geom_boxplot uses width = .75).
Using a minimal reproducible example based on mtcars:
library(ggplot2)

litter <- mtcars[c("cyl", "am", "mpg")]
litter$am <- factor(litter$am)

names(litter) <- c("trtlit", "Site", "SppCov")

pd <- position_dodge(width = .9)

ggplot(litter, aes(Site, SppCov, fill = factor(trtlit))) +
  geom_violin() +
  theme(
    axis.ticks = element_line(colour = "black", size = 2),
    axis.ticks.length = unit(0.2, "cm"), axis.text = element_text(size = 18)
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("white", "grey", "steelblue", "chartreuse3", "darkorange")
  ) +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", stackdir = "center", dotsize = 0.4, position = pd) +
  stat_summary(
    fun.data = "mean_se", geom = "pointrange",
    color = "black", size = 0.75, position = pd
  ) +
  stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.1, position = pd) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")


